# C++ compiler cannot find Boost libraries even after installing them

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, ubuntu-14.04

While compiling few test applications, I get the following error:

```
g++: error: −lboost_system: No such file or directory
g++: error: −lboost_filesystem: No such file or directory
```

while running the following command:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/boost/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  aescuda.cpp -o test.o −lboost_system −lboost_filesystem
```

The libraries are installed and present in location as shown below:

```
<prompt>$ ll  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 49178 Jun 20  2014 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    25 Jun 20  2014 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so -> libboost_system.so.1.54.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14536 Jun 20  2014 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0
<prompt>$ ll  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 217628 Jun 20  2014 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     29 Jun 20  2014 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so -> libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  88936 Jun 20  2014 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0
```

Can anyone suggest where am I going wrong :(

Comment: Was `ldconfig` run when they were installed?

Comment: Yes I have performed ldconfig. I am now facing the following problem..    obj/x86_64/release/aescuda.cpp.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_aescuda.cpp':
aescuda.cpp:(.text.startup+0x68b): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()']   ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong character in front of the `l`:

```
−lboost_system
```

It should be an ASCII hyphen:

```
-lboost_system
```

This causes the compiler driver to treat the whole string as an input file name (which obviously does not exist, hence the *No such file or directory* error), and not as an option to be passed to the linker.

(Perhaps consider switching the terminal font.)

Comment: Thanks that helped... but now another error has appeared:      **obj/x86_64/release/aescuda.cpp.o: In function _GLOBAL__sub_I_aescuda.cpp': aescuda.cpp:(.text.startup+0x68b): undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category()**.... any suggestions??